# Imported CSV data points showing in wrong location

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, csv, google

I have vector points I have uploaded in a CSV file. The coordinates from the surveyor were in Map Grid of Australia (MGA2020).
The base map I use is Google Maps which I also change the CRS to MGA2020 however when I add the vector points they appear somewhere in France rather than Australia.

Additionally when I move my cursor over the screen the co-ordinates shown on the lower toolbar next to the scale look wrong to me.

[image]

Comment: Could you share a sample of the coordinates ?

Comment: MGA2020 is a UTM projection, please share sample coordinates and the UTM Zone they're in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The steps for getting the projections right in this case:

1. Set the right projection on your csv file in the import dialouge
2. Do not touch the projection of google maps (or any other prepared geodataset (see below))
3. Set a projection on the project (Project -> Properties -> CRS) to get the final map in the projection you want it

The way you describe what you have done, it sounds to me as if you have changed the google maps projection in the layers properties under Source. This projection should never be touched unless it is wrongly defined in the data source.

Comment: Thank you. I will try again with your above steps.

Comment: Yes I was changing Google maps projection.

Comment: I've followed your steps and it's now showing how it should be. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Great! Please mark the answer as accepted to make it easier for those who need it in the future to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I was just about to add on to what @MortenSickel suggested. Exactly how it should go.
Glad you have it sorted.
I also use 2020/55 for my projections.
*Food for thought* - when dealing with DMS etc..
When we get csv of points - I will convert the coordinates into Easting and Northing to accommodate my ESPG: 7855.
I use https://geodesyapps.ga.gov.au/geographic-to-grid

^ This of course is handy when what is given is Lat/Lon.